# How do I set this up the right way, transferring from Wordpress as CMS?

Tags: craft-features

I'm trying to do something I'm used to in Wordpress, but can't really find a right way, or 'correct' way. What I was used to do in Wordpress; every page had a few options, like center content, background image, etc. In page.php (if you know Wordpses this'll make sense) I called a function pageDetails() (defined in functions.php) which returned me some variables for centering content, if it had a background image, etc.

Now I'm trying to do the same in Craft, so I created a section for the pages, added some custom fields to the pages, and now I'm trying to create a likewise method for defining a function once and use that for different 'entry types' to avoid repeating myself for each entry type template. For this, I keep coming back to creating a macro, that I define in _macros/macro.twig (for example). But, I can't get it to return variables.

In short; is there a way to use 'variables' from entry template, to the macro, and have the macro return vars (or array) to the entry template so I can use them in there? Or should I completely rethink this way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your variables are coming from the entry, you want to look into the [Twig {% embed %} docs](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html). I generally do something along these lines:

**Your main page template**

```
{% extends "_inc/_layout" %}
{% block content %}

    {% include '_inc/_title' %}
    {% embed "_inc/_body_field" %}
        {% block body_field %}{% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}

{% endblock %}
```

**Your body field**

```
{% import '_inc/_macros' as macros %}

{% block body_content %}

    {% for brick in entry.body %}

        {% if brick.type == "heading" %}

            <{{ brick.headingWeight }} class="wrap">{{ brick.heading }}</{{ brick.headingWeight }}>

        {% elseif brick.type == "wysiwyg" %}

            <div class="wrap">
                {% if brick.cappedWidth %}
                    <div class="capped">{{ brick.copy }}</div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ brick.copy }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>

        {% elseif brick.type == "inlineImage" %}

            {% set img = brick.image.first() %}
            <div class="wrap img-container">
                {{ macros.img(img, 990, {alt: brick.imageAlt}) }}
            </div>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Actually, now that I've stripped that down to some generic stuff, you'd be able to achieve the same with a simple [{% include %}](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html).

If you're using structures, you could also take this further and look into having a single file that includes a different file depending on the page type:

```
{% extends "_inc/_layout" %}

{% block main %}

    {# Call on the entry type file #}
    {% include '_types/_' ~ entry.type %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros are intended to output to the page, rather than return data to the caller. If you must return the data, I'd suggest writing a custom plugin (although that's where my knowledge stops!).